# Calculation of Carbon Quantum Dots using Quantum ESPRESSO

Tags: quantum-espresso, quantum-dots

I have build a carbon quantum dots model based on [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S002554082030413X?via%3Dihub). The model looks like this.
[image: Carbon Quantum Dots]
I have calculated the density of states of the system, but does not get a desired plot as written on the paper, where I have used all the calculation parameters, and used the Martyna-Tuckerman isolation approximation. Do we have to place the carbon dots centered on the slab or not?

here I attach the input file

```
 &CONTROL
    prefix='CD',
    calculation='nscf'

    ! this is a comment: you can comment out variables

    ! if "pseudo_dir" and "outdir" are not set then pw.x will use the
    ! values of ESPRESSO_PSEUDO and ESPRESSO_TMPDIR environmental
    ! variables instead

    pseudo_dir = './' 
    outdir     = './'
    forc_conv_thr = 1.D-3
 /

 &SYSTEM
    assume_isolated      =  'martyna-tuckerman',
    
    ibrav = 0

    ecutwfc =  40.0,
    ! ecutrho =  200.0,

    nat =  36,
    ntyp =  2,
    occupations = 'tetrahedra'
   ! nbnd = 16
 /

 &ELECTRONS
 /
 &IONS
 /

ATOMIC_SPECIES 
   C   12.011   C.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF 
   H    1.008   H.pbe-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
30.000  0.000   0.000
 0.000 30.000   0.000
 0.000  0.000  20.000

ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom
C             8.5462621381        4.9352704182        2.1665564044
C             6.4373654591        6.1820127934        2.1703856013
C            12.8220212514        2.4973076753        2.1710347238
C            10.6869630940        3.7016165802        2.1666033071
C            10.6869977938        6.1690052966        2.1666679282
C             8.5473450969        7.4020250382        2.1689283141
H             6.5837867671        8.3207094980        2.1751996955
H            14.6031401577        3.6910972572        2.1750078567
C            12.8265277052        4.9352319145        2.1683557667
C            12.8218797269        7.3735673434        2.1710486116
C            10.6585604846        8.6197131665        2.1712617450
H             8.7348277727        0.3069708431        2.1753938040
H             8.7346720352        9.5642436965        2.1754142098
H             6.5837231039        1.5502809217        2.1751931456
H            14.6028741922        6.1797799841        2.1749918454
C            10.6585195064        1.2515604438        2.1712396897
C             8.5471647526        2.4689718575        2.1688499751
C             6.4370401843        3.6887382822        2.1703651805
C             9.2602441002        6.1688733768        2.1668738975
C             7.1255349047        7.3723867294        2.1710855921
C            13.5108411137        3.6879265513        2.1708509067
C            11.4011655841        4.9352403580        2.1665635098
C            11.3980457359        7.4030366334        2.1688980356
C             9.2832769042        8.6198688495        2.1714504976
C            13.5105659673        6.1826926707        2.1708532156
H            13.3648925590        8.3212521816        2.1750960061
H            11.2078389607        0.3073902866        2.1750886619
H            11.2080342434        9.5637915261        2.1750893667
C             9.2832602314        1.2514362035        2.1714129641
C             7.1253496881        2.4985921119        2.1710436800
H             5.3450905652        3.6925837470        2.1747413063
H            13.3649457028        1.5496390540        2.1750964762
C            11.3981895508        2.4678995614        2.1688455526
C             9.2602511487        3.7017697140        2.1668157323
C             7.1221650973        4.9352790632        2.1682921936
H             5.3454007203        6.1783603711        2.1747286010

K_POINTS automatic ! gamma
10 10 1  0 0 0
```

Comment: Please share the input file you used. In your case of BURAI, select `DOS` from the bottom-right menu and then click on the bottom-left three-bar menu and select `input file`. You can copy-paste the whole input file from there to your question and add it as a code block.

Comment: The paper you cited does not seem to have a DOS plot. They have a PDOS plot which I don't think is obtainable using BURAI. You can use the [projwfc.x](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PROJWFC.html) for that.

Comment: @Earmen  I have attached the input file

Comment: i have calculate pDOS using projwfc.x, all i got is zero pDOS below the fermi level. it's really weird

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce your calculation since it's beyond the computational power I have access to. Could you share your output files (scf and nscf) and outdir contents so that I can look into this issue further? And to talk about it more, you can ping me in Quantum ESPRESSO [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117642/quantum-espresso)

Comment: The paper you link to is extremely poor in its calculation methodology, please don't try to reproduce it. Unless it's a typo, 40 eV cut-off energy is catastrophically bad even for the softest pseudopotentials, 5 x 5 x 1 kpoint grid is pointless for an isolated system, and the DOS for an isolated system is a set of delta-functions, whereas they have clearly used a fixed broadening width (prob. Gaussian).

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?  Were the comments by Phil and Abdul helpful?

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.